# Which type should be used for property with nested data structure in aws cdk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I read AWS CDK docs, especially CloudFront construct example, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront/README.html#). And i see 2 ways how `default_behavior` can be specified in cloudfront `Distribution` construct. It's like this:

```
import aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront as cloudfront
cloudfront.Distribution(self, "myDist",
    default_behavior=BehaviorOptions(origin=origins.S3Origin(my_bucket))
)
```

Or like this:

```
import aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront as cloudfront
cloudfront.Distribution(self, "myDist",
    default_behavior={"origin": origins.LoadBalancerV2Origin(lb)}
)
```

As you can see in first variant `default_behavior` accept `BehaviorOptions` nested data structure, described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront/BehaviorOptions.html#aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront.BehaviorOptions).

In second variant `default_behavior` accept just dict.

I am confused because in doc for `Distribution` construct [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront/Distribution.html) see that `default_behavior` property accept *only* `BehaviorOptions` type. Is it implicitly meaning of CDK that dict also permitted everywhere where nested data structures expected or where i'm wrong? Please help)

[image: Screenshot from definition Distribution construct]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Python but since CDK is written in Javascript/Typescript (https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk), and gets "ported" to Python and other languages through jsii (https://github.com/aws/jsii). Therefore, you can check CDK Javascript reference: by looking at (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-cloudfront/distributionprops.html#aws_cloudfront_DistributionProps_defaultBehavior), I feel you should use `BehaviorOptions` type.

You can always experiment with deploying your CDK project and check the CloudFormation stack deployed.

Comment: Thanks Chris for answer, i have checked and template rendered fine in both ways, so i feel that this is just not documented yet, but   hard to believe that i found for easy this gap in documentation.